Compose VerticalPager not transitioning to next page on fling with NestedScrollConnection
Problem
This behavior worked fine before some recent Compose dependency updates, where the VerticalPager API transitioned out of its experimental state. After the update:
When the user scrolls to the end of the expanded text and flings downward, the onPreFling and onPreScroll methods in the custom NestedScrollConnection are invoked as expected (based on logs), but the pager does not navigate to the next page. Instead, it "settles" back on the same page.
What I Tried

Custom NestedScrollConnection
I implemented a NestedScrollConnection to handle fling gestures at the edges of the scrollable text and propagate them to the pager:

`class ScrollHandler(
    private val columnScrollState: ScrollState,
    private val pagerState: PagerState?,
    private val scope: CoroutineScope
) : NestedScrollConnection {
    private val canScrollForward
        get() = columnScrollState.canScrollForward

    private val canScrollBackward
        get() = columnScrollState.canScrollBackward

    private val currentPage
        get() = pagerState?.currentPage ?: 1

    override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
        val delta = available.y

        if (delta > 0 && !canScrollBackward) { // top reached
            scope.launch {
                pagerState?.scrollBy(-(delta))
            }
        }
        if (delta < 0 && !canScrollForward) { // end reached
            scope.launch {
                pagerState?.scrollBy(-(delta))
            }
        }
        return super.onPreScroll(available, source)
    }

    override suspend fun onPreFling(available: Velocity): Velocity {
        val velocity = available.y

        if (velocity > 0 && !canScrollBackward) { // top reached
            pagerState?.animateScrollToPage(currentPage - 1)
        }
        if (velocity < 0 && !canScrollForward) { // end reached
            pagerState?.animateScrollToPage(currentPage + 1)
        }
        return super.onPreFling(available)
    }
}`

Logs confirm that:
onPreFling is invoked when the user flings at the end of the scrollable text.
The animateScrollToPage method is called with the correct target page index.
But the pager still does not navigate to the next or previous page and remains on the current page.
this is where I use the scroll handler:
`val columnScrollState = rememberScrollState()
   val nestedScrollConnection = remember { 
        ScrollHandler(columnScrollState, pagerState, scope)
   }

    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(
        pageCount = { totalPages },
        initialPage = currentPage
    )

    VerticalPager(
        state = pagerState,
        modifier = modifier
    ) { pageIndex ->

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(bottom = MaterialTheme.spacing.medium)
                .nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)
                .verticalScroll(state = columnScrollState)
        ) { ... }
    }`

What I’m Looking For
How can I ensure that the pager properly transitions to the next or previous page when flinging at the end or top of the scrollable text?
Is there a better way to handle nested scrolling or fling gestures??
Any guidance or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated!
